# How to iterate over grouping variables to compute mean on one of more variables?

Tags: r

The sample data looks like this

```r
library(tidyverse)

# data
dummy <- tibble(length = c(10,20,40,20,30,25,40,45),
                location = c(1,1,2,5,3,2,3,2),
                environ = c(5,5,5,2,2,3,3,1))
```

I want to compute the mean of column `length` grouped by all other columns (`location`, `environ` etc.), but one at a time. One way I can do it is one by one like this

```
# mean by group variable (one at a time)
dummy %>% 
  group_by(location) %>% 
  summarise(mean(length)) %>% 
  spread(1,2)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>     `1`   `2`   `3`   `5`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    15  36.7    35    20
```

then do it for next variable and so on. However, this is not feasible though for my real dataset because I have hundreds of these variables. So one way I came up with is using `map` from `purrr` to iterate over grouping variables

```
# iterating over grouping variable
map_dfr(.x = names(dummy)[-1], 
        ~ dummy %>% 
          group_by_at(.x) %>% 
          summarise(mean(length)) %>% 
          spread(1,2)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>     `1`   `2`   `3`   `5`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    15  36.7  35    20  
#> 2    45  25    32.5  23.3
```

but the problem is that it is awefully slow for my data with >1 million rows. Resulting dataframe is what I expect as output.

I have tried doing it in following way (and several other variations) but can't really figure out how to do it

```
# there must be a way doing it like this    
map_dfr(.x = dummy, 
        ~ group_by(.x) %>% 
          summarise(mean(length)) %>%
          spread(1,2)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Any solution in `tidyverse`? It is kind of a learning opportunity for me as well. I do have a working solution in `base R` using `sapply` and `tapply` as you suggested.

Comment: @akrun, I am aware that looping over df will result in vector, I was wondering if there is a way to use that vector as a grouping variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data in long format, calculate the `mean` by group and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(dummy, cols = -length) %>%
   group_by(name, value) %>%
   summarise(length = mean(length)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = length)


#  name       `1`   `2`   `3`   `5`
#  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 environ     45  25    32.5  23.3
#2 location    15  36.7  35    20
```

---

If your data is big and efficiency is a concern you can do the same operation using `data.table` functions.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dummy)

dcast(melt(dummy, id.vars = 'length')[, .(length = mean(length)),
   .(variable, value)], variable~value, value.var = 'length')
```

Comment: This is great. This is something what I have been thinking and trying to do but wasn't sure how to. For speed purpose, the `tidyverse` solution is pretty fast at this point.

Comment: This is even nice that you can list multiple columns in `values_from` argument in `pivot_wider`. This solves two of my problems.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to `transpose` or `spread` at the end instead of doing this on the loop

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(purrr)
map(names(dummy)[-1], ~ 
       dummy %>%
           select(length, .x) %>%
           group_by(group = !! rlang::sym(.x))%>% 
           summarise(Mean = mean(length)) %>% 
           ungroup) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = 'group') %>% 
  data.table::transpose(., make.names = 'group')
#  1        2    3        5
#1 15 36.66667 35.0 20.00000
#2 45 25.00000 32.5 23.33333
```

---

Or an option with `pivot_longer/pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(dummy, cols = -length) %>%   
    pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = length,
         values_fn = list(length = mean))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  name       `1`   `5`   `2`   `3`
#  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 location    15  20    36.7  35  
#2 environ     45  23.3  25    32.5
```

If there are multiple columns

```
dummy$width <- dummy$length
pivot_longer(dummy, cols = -c(length, width)) %>%   
     pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = c(length, width),
          values_fn = list(length = mean, width = mean))
# A tibble: 2 x 9
#  name     length_1 length_5 length_2 length_3 width_1 width_5 width_2 width_3
#  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 location       15     20       36.7     35        15    20      36.7    35  
#2 environ        45     23.3     25       32.5      45    23.3    25      32.5
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(dummy), id.vars = 'length'), 
        variable ~ value, value.var = 'length', mean)
```

Or for multiple columns

```
dcast(melt(setDT(dummy), id.vars = c('length', 'width')), 
        variable ~ value, value.var = c('length','width'), mean)
#   variable length_1 length_2 length_3 length_5 width_1  width_2 width_3  width_5
#1: location       15 36.66667     35.0 20.00000      15 36.66667    35.0 20.00000
#2:  environ       45 25.00000     32.5 23.33333      45 25.00000    32.5 23.33333
```

Comment: It seems better and readable. Now how can this be extended to if I have multiple variables? Let's say I have `width` as well. How do I compute mean of both `length` and `width`? In @Ronak's answer I can do it by just including another term in `summarise` step. How can I do it using `values_fn` argument in `pivot_wider`?